# error with earth function using MARS algo

Tags: r, machine-learning, training-data, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I run my ML algo:

```
EarthAlgo<-earth(cible~., data=train, degree=4, glm=list(family=binomial))
```

I got:

`Error in leaps.setup(x = bx, y = y, force.in = 1, force.out = NULL, intercept = FALSE,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)`

When I try with `train<-train[(1:dim(train)[1]-2),]`, it's ok. I search last two line on my train data set but i do not see error.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Could you provide a reproductible exemple ?